# using fp open to write a file data

Tags: php, file, fopen

I am trying to write following `$routeconfig` below to a file however I am only getting the following result how can I make it so it writes the full `$route[] = data`?

**Result:**

```
screenings/details/$1/$2
page/load/2949/screenings
```

**Code:**

```
public function hook_process()
    {
        if (!file_exists('../cache/'.DOMAIN_NAME.'-routes.php'))
        {
            $modelData = $this->CI->routes_hook->getData();

            foreach($modelData as $data)
            {
                if($data['post_url_link'] == 'screenings')
                {
                  $routeConfig[] = $route['screenings/details/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'screenings/details/$1/$2';
                  $routeConfig[] = $route['screenings'] = 'page/load/'.$data['post_id'].'/'.$data['post_url_link'].'';
                }

                $output = implode("\n", $routeConfig);

                $fp = fopen(''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cache/'.DOMAIN_NAME.'-routes.php', 'w+');

                fwrite($fp, $output);

                fclose($fp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/function.fopen.php) - **'w+'** *Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $route[] part is being interpreted as a variable, which doesn't exist.  You need to treat it as a string:

```
 $routeConfig[] = "\$route['screenings/details/(:any)/(:any)'] = \"screenings/details/\$1/\$2\"";
 $routeConfig[] = "\$route['screenings'] = \"page/load/$data['post_id']/$data['post_url_link']\"";
```

Comment: Thanks Dave how would I go about the 2nd line that has the PHP

Comment: I added a second line ... but can you update your question to show exactly what you want?

Comment: Thanks Dave,  I have tried that before I asked you haha.  This is what I am getting in my text editor and its causing a white page http://d.pr/i/nOUn

Comment: What I mean is .. what should the final output look like?

Comment: 'page/load/2949/screenings'

Comment: You literally want that?  Or do you want:  $route['screenings'] = 'page/load/2949/screenings' .  Your question makes it seem like 'page/load/2949/screenings' is *not* what you want.

Comment: The above is done by the post_id and post url link - if I can get them working via the string it would be great Dave as i do want the /id/link